# Extracting field from Some in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-option

I know the fact that a Some object can be a None or one of the objects I passed. What is the ideal way of extracting a field from the Some object given the fact that it is not None?
I have made a class 'At' that has 'date' as one of its fields. Since the Some class has a mixin with Product trait, the following works fine:

```
(An object with return type Some(At)).productElement(0).asInstanceOf[At].date
```

But is there an ideal way to do this?

Comment: use the `Option`'s `fold` method of `Option` class to extract value. Or pattern matching.

Comment: Take a look at [scala.Option Cheat Sheet](http://web.archive.org/web/20131206133026/http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/#fn1). Unfortunately it's deleted, so I guess we should beckup it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several safe ways to work with `Option`. If you want to retrieve the contained value, I would suggest you to use either `fold`, `getOrElse` or pattern matching.

```
opt.fold { /* if opt is None */ } { x => /* if opt is Some */ }

opt.getOrElse(default)

// matching on options should only be used in special cases, most of the time `fold` is sufficient
opt match {
  case Some(x) =>
  case None =>
}
```

If you want to modify the value and pass it on to somewhere else without extracting it from the `Option`, you can use `map`, `flatMap`, `filter / withFilter` etc. and therefore also for-comprehensions:

```
opt.map(x => modify(x))

opt.flatMap(x => modifyOpt(x)) // if your modification returns another `Option`

opt.filter(x => predicate(x))

for {
  x <- optA
  y <- optB
  if a > b
} yield (a,b)
```

Or if you want to perform a side-effect, you can use `foreach`

```
opt foreach println

for (x <- opt) println(x)
```

Comment: I guess we should combine all methods in a single answer. Would you add to your answer `match`, `map` + `getOrElse`, `for-comprehension` (with and without `yield`), `foreach` and so on?

Comment: This link could be helpful: [scala.Option Cheat Sheet](http://web.archive.org/web/20131206133026/http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/#fn1). Original post is deleted, so I guess you should safe as much as you can. I'll delete my answer as soon as @Core_Dumped will anaccept it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways:

1) You can use 'get' method. But you should use only if you are 300% sure that there wouldn't be None. As you will get `java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get`.

> ```
> val option: Option[At] = getAtMethod
> val dateField = option.get.date
> ```

2) As Option is a monad you can use 'map' method:

> ```
> val option: Option[At] = ...
> val optionalDate: Option[Date] = option map { _.date }
> ```

or you can use it:

```
option map { at => myMethod(at.date) }
```