# Scala: "getOrElse" in a block

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala & everyone tells that it's bad to use something like `if myFoo.get is null then` when `myFoo` is wrapped in an `Option` (Such as `Option[myFoo]`) in Scala

I keep coming across `getOrElse` but all the answers referring to getOrElse just confuses me even more even though it sounds so simple ("getOrElse").

---

Here's what I'm trying to do. If `myFoo` is null then do `something` but if it's not then do `somethingElse`.

**Could someone please explain it in the most simplest way possible for me?** Doesn't have to be a long answer but I'd appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you have not an `Option`, but some value that could be `null`:

> If myFoo is null

In this case you have to wrap it with `Option`: `Option(myFoo)`.

```
val result = Option(myFoo) match {
  case Some(value) =>
    // something
    // you could use `value` here
  case None =>
    // something else
}
```

`Option(myFoo)` wraps `myFoo` with `Option`: if it's `null` you'll get `None` otherwise you'll get `Some(myFoo)`.

See this article: [scala.Option Cheat Sheet](http://web.archive.org/web/20131206133026/http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/#fn1) for methods to work with `Option`.

Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700322/406435).

Note that if `myFoo` is an `Option`, than you don't need to wrap it: replace `Option(myFoo) match` with `myFoo match`.

Also you should note that `get` on empty `Option` (on `None`) throws an exception instead of returning `null`:

> if myFoo.get is null then

You'll get an exception, not `null`. You should never use `get`.

Comment: @Jon: Note that if `myFoo` is actually an `Option` you don't need to wrap it - replace `Option(myFoo) match` with `myFoo match`.

Answer (score 2):

Option can be two types: Some and None. None denotes the abscence of some contained value while Some denotes that it has a value. Think of Option as a list of 1 element. So when you do a getOrElse, what you're really saying is give me that value or if empty, give me this other value.

Comment: Thank you. This answer and @senia's made it super clear for me