# How to assign to Option only if it is None

Tags: ruby, scala

In ruby it is possible to do it like so:

```
first ||= number
```

and *first* will get the value of number only if it is *nil*

How to do similar thing in scala?

So far I've come up with this and it doesn't look as nice as in ruby.

```
var first: Option[Int] = None
...
first = if (first == None) Option(number) else first
// or
first = Some(first.getOrElse(number))
```

Comment: A whopping three characters shorter, you could do `first = first.orElse(Some(number))`...

Comment: @Miichi, saving three characters is a big deal at [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: here is another 1 character saved: `first = first orElse Some(number)`

Comment: "and `first` will get the value of number only if it is `nil`" – No, it will get the value of the number if it is either `nil` or `false` or uninitialized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not the best practice or anything, but here is something similar you can do:

```
scala> implicit class RubyFriend[T](val value: Option[T]) extends AnyVal {
     |   def ||=(alt: T): Option[T] = value orElse Some(alt)
     | }
defined class RubyFriend

scala> var something: Option[Int] = None
something: Option[Int] = None

scala> something = something ||= 5
something: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> something ||= 4
res11: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> (None: Option[Int]) ||= 3
res12: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

We create an implicit conversion from `Option` to `RubyFriend` which has `||=` method. It's a pimp my library pattern. The only difference that it can't really assign to the original variable because in Scala assignment can't be overloaded as far as I know.

Overall try to avoid vars in Scala.

Here is another attempt to make it even more Ruby like:

```
scala> import scala.language.implicitConversions
import scala.language.implicitConversions

scala> implicit class RubyFriend[T](var value: Option[T]) {
     |   def ||=(alt: T): Unit = value = value orElse Some(alt)
     | }
defined class RubyFriend

scala> implicit def ruby2Option[T](smth: RubyFriend[T]): Option[T] = smth.value
ruby2Option: [T](smth: RubyFriend[T])Option[T]

scala> var ropt: RubyFriend[Int] = None
ropt: RubyFriend[Int] = RubyFriend@2d483fef

scala> ropt.value
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> val opt: Option[Int] = ropt
opt: Option[Int] = None

scala> ropt ||= 6

scala> ropt.value
res2: Option[Int] = Some(6)

scala> val opt: Option[Int] = ropt
opt: Option[Int] = Some(6)

scala> ropt ||= 7

scala> ropt.value
res4: Option[Int] = Some(6)
```

This makes a wrapper class around `Option` and implicitly converts back and forth. At the same time an optional value is presented as **mutable** field (yikes).

These both examples are just to show what's possible in Scala not really a good way of doing it :).

A "refinement" of the first example as suggested by @senia:

```
scala> implicit class RubyFriend[T](val value: Option[T]) extends AnyVal {
     |   def ||(alt: T): Option[T] = value orElse Some(alt)
     | }
defined class RubyFriend

scala> var something: Option[Int] = None
something: Option[Int] = None

scala> something ||= 5

scala> something
res1: Option[Int] = Some(5)

scala> something ||= 6

scala> something
res3: Option[Int] = Some(5)
```

Comment: You could rename your method to `||` and use it like `something ||= 5`. And it will reassign a value to `var`. Actually it will be just like the method `?+?` in my answer.

Comment: Also note that name `||` can confuse other developers - there is already method `||` for `Boolean`.

Comment: If only it would be possible via lazy val but apparently it's not. If it's possible to use vals only without making it unreadable and inefficient (considering that input could be a very long string), let me know. The full code is here http://pastie.org/private/cyesgwrxrfkgxpnegnnhg

Comment: @HappyCoder: just use a tail recursion. `first` and `previous` - parameters. matches - also as parameter, convert it to `Stream` like this: `"""(\d+)(,)?""".r.findAllMatchIn(numbers).toStream`.

Comment: @HappyCoder: note that `if (previous.get != lastNumber)` is unsafe (just like `first.get - 1`). You should never use `get` method on `Option`.

Comment: @senia thanks for the tip! Now it looks like this http://pastie.org/private/awggjmrr99ktw6tg3dxaa

Comment: Please kindly explain why calling get is unsafe and what is the alternative? I decided to use Option because it's the scala way. In java I would just use an Integer and null instead of None.

Comment: @HappyCoder: you should get rid of `get`. And don't forget to add `@annotation.tailrec` just in case...

Comment: @HappyCoder: alternatives: `map`,  `getOrElse`, `match` and [so on](http://web.archive.org/web/20131206133026/http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/scalaoption-cheat-sheet/). With `get` you could gen an exception. With other methods you'll get an exception only in case you'll throw this exception explicitly.

Comment: @HappyCoder: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700167/extracting-field-from-some-in-scala

Comment: Will calling .isDefined before .get suffice (just like I do now)? At other case the code is also guarded against exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) operator for this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

none[Int] <+> 1.some
// Some(1)

2.some <+> 1.some
// Some(2)
```

You could use `a <+>= b` instead of `a = a <+> b`:

```
var i = none[Int] // i == None
i <+>= 1.some // i == Some(1)
i <+>= 2.some // i == Some(1)
```

See also **Plus[F[_]]** in [scalaz cheatsheet](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/scalaz-cheatsheet.html).

For `Option` `plus` is [implemented](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/64aaeb89646586d6249addc01962c515daee7b90/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Plus.scala#L32) as `orElse`.

For collections (`List`, `Vector`, `Stream`, etc) `Plus` is implemented as `append`:

```
Vector(1, 2) <+> Vector(3, 4)
// Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I can't find a method to combine `Option[T]` and `T` in the way you want, but you could write such method like this:

```
implicit class PlusT[T, M[_]: Plus : Applicative](m: M[T]) {
  def ?+?(t: T) = m <+> t.point[M]
}

none[Int] ?+? 1
// Some(1)

2.some ?+? 1
// Some(2)

var i = none[Int] // i == None
i ?+?= 1 // i == Some(1)
i ?+?= 2 // i == Some(1)
```

You could rename this method to `||` and use it like `||=` just like in `Ruby`, but this name can confuse other developers - there is already method `||` for `Boolean`.

Comment: can you detail more about the operator for Scalaz fans please?

Comment: @Edmondo1984: what can I add to my answer? see default implementations [here](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/64aaeb89646586d6249addc01962c515daee7b90/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Plus.scala).

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why other poster deleted his answer, but I would go for the approach also suggested in the comments:

```
first = first orElse Some(number)
```