# Retrieve value from Some in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I am trying to retrieve case object used for creating enum from string

Taking reference from 
[Extracting field from Some in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700167/extracting-field-from-some-in-scala)

```
sealed trait Mapping {def code: Int;def desc: Symbol}

object types {

  case object TypeA extends Mapping {
    val code = 0;
    val desc = 'A
  }

  case object TypeB extends Mapping {
    val code = 1;
    val desc = 'B
  }

  val values=List(TypeA,TypeB)
  def getType(desc: Symbol) =
    values.find(_.desc == desc)
 }
```

The below code makes me able to retrive value back from `Some(TypeA)`

```
     var s=types.getType('A)
```

Approach 1

```
  s match{
    case Some(value)=>print(value.code)
  }
```

Approach 2

```
     print(s.fold {-1} { x => x.code })
```

Following are the queries

1. I am not clear about the second approach Can anyone explain how fold
   is working here
2. I want use a default type case object to represent
   `None` in case no match is found

Comment: `.fold` either apply `=> Int = -1` if `None`, or `x => x.code` inside `Option` (as `.map`/`.flatMap`) if there is `Some` defined value. Similar to `.map` + `.getOrElse`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am not clear about the second approach Can anyone explain how fold is working here

This is the signature of `fold`:

```
def fold[B](ifEmpty: ⇒ B)(f: (A) ⇒ B): B
```

the first argument `ifEmpty` is the "default" value that will be returned in case the `Option` is empty, whereas the second argument `f` is the function that gets executed on the value contained by the Option (if it's there).

```
opt.fold(a)(f)
```

is then equivalent to

```
opt.map(f).getOrElse(a)
```

or

```
opt match {
  case None => a
  case Some(v) => f(v)
}
```

> I want use a default type case object to represent None in case no match is found

You can do something like:

```
sealed trait Mapping {def code: Int;def desc: Symbol}

object types {

  case object TypeA extends Mapping {
    val code = 0;
    val desc = 'A
  }

  case object TypeB extends Mapping {
    val code = 1;
    val desc = 'B
  }

  case object DefaultType extends Mapping {
    val code = -1
    val desc = 'Default
  }

  val values = List(TypeA,TypeB)
  def getType(desc: Symbol): Mapping =
    values.find(_.desc == desc).getOrElse(DefaultType)
 }
```

Comment: `print(s.fold {-1} { x => x.code })` how to use DefaultType with fold

Comment: `var s=types.getType('A)
   s match{
    case Some(value)=>print(value.code)
  }` gives compile error as return type is mapping

Comment: @coder25 if you're using my last example `getType` returns a `Mapping` (it falls back to the default automatically), so you can just do `types.getType('A).code`

Comment: otherwise you can stick to your implementation and do `s.fold(types.DefaultType)(x => x.code)`. But this won't work because of a type inference issue with multiple parameters list. You can either do `s.fold((types.DefaultType: Mapping)(x => x.code)` or simply don't use `fold` and do `s.map(x => x.code).getOrElse(types.DefaultType)`

Answer (score 4):

1. If you just want to print out the contents, the way to go is `s.foreach(println(_.code))`
2. ```
   s match{
    case Some(value)=>print(value.code)
   }
   ```

   Is a bad idea, because it will crash when `s` is `None`. You should add a `case` clause to match that case (but again, you are better off just using `foreach` in this case).
3. `s.fold {-1} { x => x.code }` is equivalent to `s.map(_.code).getOrElse(-1)`
4. If you want default type instead of `None` you can just do `println(s.getOrElse(DefaultType).code)`